# Rest position doesn't get stored

Tags: armature, vertices, pose-mode

I've been working with a model with some poses. After I was done posing, I decided to jump into doing some texture work with it.

Since Blender can't help me with the textures, I use 3D-Coat. So I decided to use 3D-Coat and exported the model as OBJ, however, when I loaded it, it had some vertices moved around, so I went back to Blender to check and I exported it still posed.

I then cleared all Rotation, Location and Scale to put the armature how it was and it worked. So I exported again to OBJ, and once again it exported it as it was posed.

I removed every single Shape Key and tried to use the cleared armature as the Rest Pose, but it didn't work and it comes back to the last pose.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest making a "zero pose" action or pose, (select all pose bones, clear all, insert locrotscale for all ) and export using that.  Clearing rotation etc from pose bones doesn't clear the keyframes which (by the sound of it) are being used by the exporter.

Answer (score 0):

Apply armature modifier and then export the model. Use a duplicate though or after exporting, back to previous step with CTRL+Z.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *Pose Mode* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Pose as Rest Pose*?